# How can I rewrite my swift code so that it also considers calculating differences between two dates when one is in the future?

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I have a class function that takes an `NSDate` object and returns a human-readable string telling the user how long ago did this date appeared. It looks like this:

```
class func timeAgoSinceDate(date:NSDate, numericDates:Bool) -> String {
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let now = NSDate()
    let earliest = now.earlierDate(date)
    let latest = (earliest == now) ? date : now
    let components:NSDateComponents = calendar.components([NSCalendarUnit.Minute , NSCalendarUnit.Hour , NSCalendarUnit.Day , NSCalendarUnit.WeekOfYear , NSCalendarUnit.Month , NSCalendarUnit.Year , NSCalendarUnit.Second], fromDate: earliest, toDate: latest, options: NSCalendarOptions())

    if (components.year >= 2) {
        return "\(components.year) years ago"
    } else if (components.year >= 1){
        if (numericDates){
            return "1 year ago"
        } else {
            return "last year"
        }
    } else if (components.month >= 2) {
        return "\(components.month) months ago"
    } else if (components.month >= 1){
        if (numericDates){
            return "1 month ago"
        } else {
            return "last month"
        }
    } else if (components.weekOfYear >= 2) {
        return "\(components.weekOfYear) weeks ago"
    } else if (components.weekOfYear >= 1){
        if (numericDates){
            return "1 week ago"
        } else {
            return "last week"
        }
    } else if (components.day >= 2) {
        return "\(components.day) days ago"
    } else if (components.day >= 1){
        if (numericDates){
            return "1 day ago"
        } else {
            return "yesterday"
        }
    } else if (components.hour >= 2) {
        return "\(components.hour) hours ago"
    } else if (components.hour >= 1){
        if (numericDates){
            return "1 hour ago"
        } else {
            return "an hour ago"
        }
    } else if (components.minute >= 2) {
        return "\(components.minute) minutes ago"
    } else if (components.minute >= 1){
        if (numericDates){
            return "1 minute ago"
        } else {
            return "a minute ago"
        }
    } else if (components.second >= 3) {
        return "\(components.second) seconds ago"
    } else {
        return "just now"
    }

}
```

I would like to rewrite this function (or - if it's easier - create another one) that also takes one `NSDate` as a parameter, but this time the input date is in the future, so the output should look like:

`in couple minutes`, `in couple hours`, `in xx seconds`, etc.

Can you help me with that?

Comment: It seems like the logic for that would be similar to what you've already written. Where are you stuck?

Comment: Not directly an answer to your question, but have you considered using `NSDateComponentsFormatter`? It roughly has the same functionality as your code.

Answer (score 0):

Far be it form me to try and stop you if you're doing this because you're specifically interested in writing this code. But if you just want the string results and are writing the code as a means to that end-- then you probably want to make things easier on yourself and use `NSDateComponentsFormatter`. Something awfully close to what you describe, that works for both past and future dates:

```
func diffString(date:NSDate) -> String {
    let now = NSDate()

    let formatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
    formatter.unitsStyle = NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStyle.Full
    formatter.allowedUnits = [ .Day, .Hour, .Minute ]

    let interval : NSTimeInterval = fabs(date.timeIntervalSinceDate(now))
    guard let intervalString = formatter.stringFromTimeInterval(interval) else {
        return ""
    }

    let resultString : String
    if now.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate > date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate {
        resultString = "\(intervalString) ago"
    } else {
        resultString = "in \(intervalString)"
    }
    return resultString
}
```

You can then do:

```
let past = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: -1000000)
let future = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 1000000)

diffString(past) // "11 days, 13 hours, 46 minutes ago"
diffString(future) // "in 11 days, 13 hours, 46 minutes"
```

Change the `allowedUnits` value for the formatter to adjust the results.